# Replacing a double nested for-loop with a lapply family in R

Tags: r, function, loops, apply, lapply

I'm currently using a double (nested) `for` loop to implement the below formula:[image].

Everything works great. But I was wondering if I could:

**(A)** Input `r` as a single number in this case `.3` instead of a matrix of `.3`s and `1`s?

**(B)** Use a `lapply` family code e.g., `mapply` instead of a nested `for`-loop?

```
V <- c(.25, .5, .75) 
m <- length(V)

r <- matrix(c(1, .3, .3, .3, 1, .3, .3,.3, 1), 3, 3)

sumV <- 0 

for (i in 1:nrow(r)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(r)) {
    sumV <- sumV + r[i,j] * sqrt(V[[i]]*V[[j]])
     }
   } 

(1/m)^2 * sumV # Final answer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short version of your attempt is

```
(1/m)^2 * sum(sqrt(outer(V, V)) * r)
#[1] 0.2599292
```

`outer` multiplies every element with every other element which is what double loop is doing. We then take `sqrt` of all the values, multiply with `r` matrix, `sum` them  and multiply by `(1/m)^2`.

---

We want to multiply the diagonal elements with 1 and rest of them with `r` value which is easy when `r` is a matrix however, if it is a single number we need to construct the matrix accordingly.

```
r <- .3
mat <- sqrt(outer(V, V))
mult_matrix <- matrix(r, ncol(mat), nrow(mat))
diag(mult_matrix) <- 1
(1/m)^2 * sum(mat * mult_matrix)
#[1] 0.2599292
```